# Pipeline aggregations in ElasticSearch 1.5

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I'm wondering if it is, in any way, possible to make `ES` run aggregations on other aggregations all in the same query?

Basically, that's called pipelining.

I'm talking about `ElasticSearch 1.5`, yes I know, that's unfortunate but I'm stuck with `AWS` and that's what they're selling, I have to live with that.

---

I'm guessing that is not possible, so I'll write the next phase of the question right away.

Assuming I can query `ES` multiple times based on results from previous queries, how would you do the following:

1. Have a list of the top 100 tags that sorted by the number of appearances in the documents? (I have a field `tags` for each record, I'd like to know which tags are the most common) - **in the past hour**.
2. Having that, for each of the 100 tags; have the number of appearances split by 1-hour buckets (denote by `Y` **the number representing the last hour**).
3. Then, calculate the by how many percents, `Y` deviates from the average value of all the other 1-hour buckets.

Thank you for helping !!!

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, that's called pipelining.

No. Pipeline Aggregations did not appear until Elasticsearch 2.0. For what it's worth, Elastic does offer its own [ESaaS offering with Elastic Cloud](https://www.elastic.co/cloud). It also runs on AWS.

> ... how would you do the following

The first two follow more of a flow of *scope* rather than working on the values.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "range" : {
          "timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-1h"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you the last hour of data.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_tag": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tag",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you the top 100 tags for all time.

If you put them together, then you get the top 100 tags in the past hour.

For the second request, it sounds like you want a mix of that, but you also want more than just the last hour.

Whenever performing an aggregation (or `GROUP BY` query for that matter), you need to think about incremental steps. If you want to group by hour, then do something, then that's the order that it needs to happen in. So it's not a matter of "now that I have the last hour, let's get the other hours too". Once you've narrowed you window (scope), then you can't go back in general.

So to get number 2, we need to look at it differently. Group by as many hours as you're interested in looking at (how many 1-hour buckets do you want), then get those and then get the count per bucket. I'll take a guess and say that you want 24, 1-hour buckets (note 24 * 100 is 2400, which is not insignificant!).

That's a lot of buckets, so maybe we can think about the question differently.

1. I want the last hour results of top 100.
2. I want all top 100 average *for X time* (where you define X, and having it reduced will make it faster, but naturally limited to the window of selection). By limiting with the filter, we reduce the scope of the overall aggregation:

This may look like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "range" : {
          "timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-24h"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_hour_and_day": {
      "date_range": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "ranges": [
          { "from": "now-1h" },
          { "to": "now-1h" }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_tag": {
          "field": "tag",
          "size": 100
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this request is that it gives you `now-24 to now-1h`, then `now-1h` to `now`. That's pretty loosely what you requested, but it doesn't give it by term (which may or may not matter). Instead, the term is given by time instead (again, steps/order matters). You can then say that the previous 24h average is the responding doc count of the wider window, divided by the window size (23 in this case for 23 hours). If you want to include the last hour in the average, then you can change `"to": "now-1h"` to `"to": "now"`.

We can perhaps flip this to give us the answer differently, but with a little bit more effort (where query still limits by the max time range to consider):

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": { ... },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_tag": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tag",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_range": {
          "field": "timestamp",
          "ranges": [
            { "from": "now-1h" },
            { "to": "now-1h" }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that now we aggregate by tag first across the full scope. You could remove the second `date_range` aggregation as a result because you now have the *total* for the time window. The problem with this approach is that you could end up with a very popular tag in the last hour that is not popular enough in the past full range, and *so it won't appear at all*.

The solution to that is to add an extra step unfortunately, by making two top-level aggregations. One for the top 100 in the full scope and one for the top 100 in the last hour.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": { ... },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_tag": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tag",
        "size": 100
      }
    },
    "group_by_last_hour": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-1h"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "tag",
          "size": 100
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives the top 100 for the full window -- whatever that might be -- and then it also separately gives the top 100 for the last hour.

> Then, calculate the by how many percents, Y deviates from the average value of all the other 1-hour buckets.

Do this on the client side based on whichever form you care to use, and calculate the average by cross-comparing.

And considering the type of query, you should then cache the result, which allows you to play with larger window sizes than might be otherwise desirable.